# Unable to read SMS(OTP) with SMS Retriever API in Android10(Android Q)

Tags: android, android-10.0

My App is already on play store having thousands of downloads & works perfectly great except Android10(Android Q), Since Android 10 release it gets stuck to a LoginScreen. As LoginScreen includes OTP Verification with User Mobile Number,after login button click SMS Retriever API gets started & OTP Received but not able to read it & BroadcastReceiver always goes to TimeOut conditions. Later I unregister it (BroadcastReceiver)on onDestroy.I tested it against OnePlus6.Please suggest any solution to this.

My Code:

```
private void startSMSRetriver()
{
       SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(NewLogInActivity.this );

    // Starts SmsRetriever, which waits for ONE matching SMS message until timeout
    // (5 minutes). The matching SMS message will be sent via a Broadcast Intent with
    // action SmsRetriever#SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            System.out.println("SMS Success");
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("SMS Failure");
        }
    });

}
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MySMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            try
            {
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                    Status status =(Status) bundle.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);
                    if(status != null)
                    {
                        switch(status.getStatusCode())
                        {
                            //I want this
                            case CommonStatusCodes. SUCCESS :
                                System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                                break;
                            //always hits timeout
                            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT :
                                System.out.println("Timeout Hit");
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Msg Exception 2 ::"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoginButton(LoginScreen) called below code:-

```
startSMSRetriver();
otpReceiver = new MySMSBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(otpReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"));
```

Comment: I know I'm one year late :), but did you manage to figure it out?